# Not getting the answer in this socket program

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

I'm trying to find the sum of the two numbers.
These are my codes for server and client,
the result I want is CLIENT RECEIVED : Sum 46
but instead I get 
CLIENT RECEIVED : Sum 12
CLIENT RECEIVED : Sum 34

**Client:**

```
# Echo client program

import socket

def parse_file(fName):
    list = []
    with open(fName) as f:
        for line in 1f:
            list.append(line.strip())
    return list


HOST = 'localhost'    # The remote host
PORT = 50007              # The same port as used by the server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))

# s.sendall('Hello, world')
# data = s.recv(1024)
# s.close()
# print 'Received', repr(data)

input_data = parse_file('foo')

for i in input_data:
    s.sendall(str(i))
    sum = s.recv(1024)
    print "CLIENT RECEIVED : Sum ", sum

s.close()
```

**Server:**

```
import socket

def compute_sum(line):
    result = sum(int(i) for i in line)
    return result

HOST = 'localhost'                 # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 50007              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    print "SERVER RECIEVED : ", repr(data)
    compute_sum(data)

    conn.sendall(data)
conn.close()
```

and the Foo contains

```
12 
34
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a list of numbers from your text file, but then only sending (and hence summing) each number one at a time. You could either have the server gather each of the numbers one at a time and *then* sum them, or send all the numbers in one go. I'd recommend the latter. Something like this:

**Client**

```
s.sendall(','.join(input_data))
sum = s.recv(1024)
```

**Server**

```
def compute_sum(line):
    return sum(int(i) for i in line.split(','))
```

That will send the numbers to the server together as a single string, e.g. `12,34`. The server will then sum the values within that single string.

Comment: There is still no guarantee that the server would receive all of the numbers in a single call to `conn.recv()`. Even if the client only calls `s.sendall()` once, it still might show up in multiple `.recv()`s.

Comment: @101 getting this output for the edit made:CLIENT RECEIVED : Sum  12,34
CLIENT RECEIVED : Sum  12,34

Comment: @Robᵩ any modification to get the output only once?